# Need a callback when it is OK to access the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I have an Angular component that fetches markdown, converts it to HTML, then inserts it into the DOM.  After insertion it does some more DOM manipulation.   So the template is this:

```
<div id="fixroot" [innerHTML]="content"></div>
```

and the component is like this:

```js
    content: string;

    ...

    async getPage(url: string) {
       try { 
           this.content = this.mdToHtml(await this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'text'}).toPromise();
           setTimeout(() => this.fixupDOM(), 400);

    ....

    fixupDom() {
       const el = document.getElementById('fixroot');
       // do stuff to the DOM element that are children of el
```

The use of `setTimeout` here is really awful, but without it the `fixupDom` method doesn't work
because the DOM is not ready when the Promise concludes.  But it has to go.

What I need is a callback (probably from the HTMLElement
`el`) that calls my routine as soon as the DOM structure is ready.  I haven't been able 
to make anything work.   Anyone know the right function?

Comment: You just need to wait a single redraw. So setTimeout with a value of 1 or maybe even 0 is enough.

Comment: @slebetman I thought that the browser's DOM rendering happens in a separate thread from the one that executes Javascript. (which, I realize, is one thread only).   So a really low timeout value might fail.  Is that wrong?

Comment: The browser's rendering is the same thread as the javascript. You can test this out yourself by loading an animated gif then write an infinite `while()` loop. The gif will not animate (browser cannot load next animation). Be careful doing this however as you may have to kill your browser (or in worse case, eg. on a slow machine like a Raspberry Pi, reboot your computer) because it will also stop the browser from handling mouse clicks etc. The browser is single threaded (for modern browsers the browser tab is single threaded) -  not just javascript

Comment: @slebetman upon experimentation it turns out you are correct.  What ended up working for me is constructing my DOM within an HTMLElement created with document.createElement(), then setting innerHTML on that, and the DOM is available in the statement after that without delay.  If you want to write that up as a response I will mark it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use the [ngAfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) hook that fires after your content has been loaded.

If you use a template reference for your div then you can access it after the `ngAfterViewInit` fires.

This is the angular way of accessing the DOM which makes it framework agnostic in case you want to run in a web worker etc...

Since you are inserting HTML you made also need to pipe that HTML through a [Sanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) because angular has a sanitizing context due to XSS.

Comment: Yes I do the sanitizer step but omitted it for clarity in the question.   However I thought ngAferViewInit is called once after framework loads the page.   The setting of the property 'content' happens after that.

Answer (score 0):

[`ngAfterContentInit` lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence) is called earlier during creation and rendering of component and directive.

You can implement it in your directive and access content to be reflected in the directive's view. For example,

```js
ngAfterContentInit() {
  const el = this.content.nativeElement;
  // mutate el as desired  
}
```

Comment: The documentation says: "It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated".   The value of the property `content` is set after that.   So that won't work for me.

Comment: `ngAfterContentChecked` is more fitting then if content mutates during the lifetime of the view